# marklogic xquery how to commit the update and then the update can be used by following lines in same xquery function?

Tags: marklogic, commit

I'm using marklogic 10 on windows 10.

I have a workflow which I want to log information for each step. So I want to have something similiar like in database, I update a data, commit, and then I can use this data immediately in the following code.
Is this doable? and how?

for example, in the following sample code, assume it is the first time I write log, I want to create the document before I log. So I create the log document, commit, and then I insert a log node into this log document. But it seems that the log document is created, but the log node is not inserted into log document. How should I make it work? the idea is I want to have a function that can insert log nodes into log files and not affected by any failure of following code

```
let $logFile := "/workflow/tracking/load-log.xml"
let $thisErrorMsg := <error>
                           <time>2020/04/10</time>
                           <desc>test</desc>
                     </error>
let $_log-file-exists := if(fn:empty(fn:doc($logFile)))
                        then
                            let $root := <errors></errors>
                            return
                            (
                              xdmp:set-transaction-mode("update")
                              ,
                              xdmp:document-insert(
                                  $logFile,
                                  $root,
                                  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
                                    <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
                                    <quality>10</quality>
                                  </options>)
                                ,
                               xdmp:commit()
                             )
                         else ()
return 
(
xdmp:set-transaction-mode("update")
,
xdmp:node-insert-child( fn:doc($logFile)/errors, $thisErrorMsg)
,
 xdmp:commit()
)
```

Thanks a lot for your help
Helen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are ways to do as you like, I would avoid needing to. Your code would become unnecessarily complex. Just write the initial doc with first error, or append.

You could also consider writing every error as a separate document. Your log file won't be easy to handle when it starts to grow big.

HTH!

Comment: Hi @grtjn, each err msg is a doc will cause too many tiny documents. I guess each date has a log document maybe better. is it right?  but then I have same issue. when I dynamically create log file, then need to add error msg to the log file in the following steps within same xquery process, the error msg won't show up in log documents.   How do I append node to document that is created in same xquery process?

Comment: Many small docs is how MarkLogic prefers it. It gives you best flexibility to slice and dice when searching through your logs. Prune or aggregate history if needed, but keep current docs small.